# JPA use stored procedure in criteria query

Tags: postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

I'm trying to define a criteria query with a function in select and in where statement.

The SQL query is:

```
select s.*, contr_topay(s.id) as rest
from spedizionestd s
where contr_topay(s.id) >0
... other conditions
... optional order by
```

**contr_topay** is the procedure in the database (Postgresql). I've defined a NamedStoredProcedure:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name = "MovimentoContrassegno.contr_topay",
        procedureName = "contr_topay",
        parameters = {
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, queryParameter = "idsped", type = Long.class, optional = false),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, queryParameter="importo", type=Double.class, optional = false),
        }
)
```

and called it with success:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = this.em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("MovimentoContrassegno.contr_dapagare");
    query.setParameter("idsped", myid);
    query.execute();
    return (Double) query.getOutputParameterValue(2);
```

Now, how can I put the procedure in the select clause and in the where condition inside a criteria query?

NB: i need criteria query because I build dynamic query with additional where conditions and "order by" choised by the user at runtime

(I'm using eclipselink 2.6.0)

Comment: A StoredProcedure is one thing. A different thing is a Criteria query. You don't put one in the other.

Comment: @NeilStockton thanks. There is a way to achieve the same mechanism used in SQL in Criteria query? Or I must write the procedure as subquery?

Comment: What would the SQL you wish to output look like?  JPA isn't what will process the results of your stored procedure, so it can be treated like any database function - you should be able to use the JPA FUNCTION or eclipseLink specific JPQL extensions: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#EclipseLink_Extensions_.28EQL.29